# Knn with dataset containing words as well as numbers

Tags: java, dataset, pseudocode, knn, nearest-neighbor

How would i be able to implement KNN on a dataset that has words in the fields as well as numbers? I understand asking questions without source codes and in depth explanations of said code is looked down upon but I just want a couple of pointers of how one may be able to go about doing this so i can be pointed in the right direction and try learn.

Pseudocode or even just bullet points explaining the steps required to achieve this would be incredibly ideal but all information will be welcome and greatly appreciated.